# What is the origin of YOLO/darknet coordinates

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, image-recognition, opencv, yolo

I am aware of that darknet/yolov3 outputs relative coordinates, would the coordinate (0,0) be at the bottom left, or at the top left?

I am confused as opencv2 seems to have the `y=0` at the top of the image as is usual when working with matrices. Yet mathematicaly and intuitively (for me at least) the coordinate (0,0) should be at the bottom left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(0, 0)`  is top left.

Here an [**a helpful blog**](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/12/practical-guide-object-detection-yolo-framewor-python/) that goes through all the features in the output vector.

This is common in image processing. There are a few reasons that this is the convention in computer vision. [**Check here for a list**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/why-is-the-origin-in-computer-graphics-coordinates-at-the-top-left), the accepted answer states:

> This is caused in the history. Early computers had Cathode Ray Tubes (CRTs) which "draw" the image with a cathode ray from the upper left corner to the lower right.